# Getting connection from Entity Manager

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection

We are trying to get the connection object from the EntityManager

Below is the sample code

```
  final Session unwrap = proxy.unwrap(Session.class);
        unwrap.doWork(new Work()
        {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException
            {
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(MY_QUERY);
                for (Object value : valueSet)
                {
                    ....
                    ....
                    ps.addBatch();
                }
                try
                {
                    int[] ints = ps.executeBatch();

                } finally
                {
                    ps.close();
                }
            }
        });
```

This works fine .

The concern we have is that when this code is invoked , everytime getConnection is called on the DataSource. Does that mean a new connection is obtained from the pool ?

This has performance impact in our use case . 
Our understanding is that the current active connection will be utilised.

Is the understanding incorrect ?

Comment: Please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161449/each-request-from-user-call-a-new-getconnection. it will answer your question.

Comment: It depends on your configuration, do you use connection pool ? how it's configure?

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate documentation says:

> Controller for allowing users to perform JDBC related work using the Connection managed by this Session.

So it is the (single) Connection used by the Session.
Everything else would be a Bug.